# Graphql-Access arguments in child resolvers

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server

I am using apollo-server and apollo-graphql-tools and I have following schema

```
type TotalVehicleResponse {
  totalCars: Int
  totalTrucks: Int
}

type RootQuery {
  getTotalVehicals(color: String): TotalVehicleResponse
}

schema {
  query: RootQuery
}
```

and Resolver functions are like this

```
{
  RootQuery: {
    getTotalVehicals: async (root, args, context) => {
      // args = {color: 'something'}
      return {};
    },
    TotalVehicleResponse: {
      totalCars: async (root, args, conext) => {
        // args is empty({}) here
        .........
        .........
      },
      totalTrucks: async (root, args, conext) => {
        // args is empty({}) here
        .........
        .........
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is that how can I access `args` which is available in root resolver(`getTotalVehicals`) in any of the child resolvers?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`args` refer strictly to the arguments provided in the query to that field. If you want values to be made available to child resolvers, you can simply return them from the parent resolver.

```
{
  RootQuery: {
    getTotalVehicles: async (root, args, context) => {
      return { color: args.color };
    },
    TotalVehicleResponse: {
      totalCars: async (root, args, context) => {
        // root contains color here
      },
      totalTrucks: async (root, args, context) => {
        // root contains color here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please have look at this comprehensive link also
https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-server-basics-demystifying-the-info-argument-in-graphql-resolvers-6f26249f613a

Comment: Please don't do this. It leads to tight coupling between resolvers and doesn't scale up well.

Each resolver should receive its own args directly from the query. Please check cYee's answer for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63300135/7948938

Comment: This looks like a workaround, it's not a proper solution.

Answer (score 21):

### TLDR: Add your *arguments* to the *field*

(Client Side) change from:

```
Car(type: $type, materialType: $materialType){
  id
  material
  name
  ...
}
```

(Client Side) To:

```
Car(type: $type){
  id,
  material(materialType: $materialType) // moved here
  name
  ...
}
```

Then, You can access `args` in server `fieldResolver` (`material` field in this case).

### *Longer version*

Do not pass your argument through `root`, except `IDs` or `parent object`, anything from client, use **field level argument**.

#### Why?

1. *Tight Coupling* and hard to scale up schemas,
2. *Difficult to troubleshoot* and debug,
3. *Leaking unnecessary information to children*,
4. *Mixing up parent object with arguments*

A simple query can grow from this:

```
[Root] Car(
  color:white
) {
  id,
  seat,
  ...
}
```

To this:

```
[Root] Car(
  color:white, 
  type:sedan, 
  seat:leather, 
  seatColor:black,
  rimColor: blue,
  rimShape: OutOfTheWorld,
  ...
) {
  id,
  seat,
  ...
}
```

Instead of passing the argument around, you can do this

```
[Root] Car(
  color:white, 
  type:sedan
  ...
) {
  id
  seat(type:leather, color:black),
  rim(color: blue, shape: OutOfTheWorld){
    // nested query
    material(hardness: high), // solved `Why no.2`: deep argument. 
    
    // More nested
    brand(trustWorthy: high) {
      priceRange(range: mid),
      area,
      ...
    },
    id
  }
  numberOfPassengers,
  ...
}
```

instead of squeezing all args into single root, now each field is responsible for its args and resolver.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Args shouldn't be shared between resolvers; this leads to coupling and it's very hard to scale up schemas that way

Comment: the best and only correct answer! thanks! it is rather hard to find clair documentation on how to handl this issue!

Answer (score 20):

If you know you are using **variables** there is another way, other than the accepted answer, using the fourth argument of the resolver function: `info`.

This `info` argument contains a field `variableValues` amongst other fields.
This field doesn't strictly contain the parent's `args`, but if your operation is executed with variables that are passed to the parent resolver, then you'll have access to them via the info.variableValues from all the relevant resolver functions.

So if your operation is called like this for example:

```
query GetTotalVehicalsOperation($color: String) {
  getTotalVehicals(color: $color) {
    totalCars
    totalTrucks   
  }
}
```

... with variables: {color: 'something'}

you'll have access to the variables from the other resolvers:

```
{
  RootQuery: {
    getTotalVehicles: async (root, args, context, info) => {
      //info.variableValues contains {color: 'something'}          
      return {};
    },
    TotalVehicleResponse: {
      totalCars: async (root, args, context, info) => {
        //same here: info.variableValues contains {color: 'something'}
      },
      totalTrucks: async (root, args, context, info) => {
        //and also here: info.variableValues contains {color: 'something'}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, this only works when using variables. So it may not a good idea to rely on info.

Comment: Thanks, @Trevor. I've updated my answer to clarify that.

Comment: Please have look at this comprehensive link also
https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-server-basics-demystifying-the-info-argument-in-graphql-resolvers-6f26249f613a