# GraphQL Resolvers - Accessing ID of parent node

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to implement a GraphQL server with the following query structure:

```
query getLists {      /// Returns an array with multiple lists
    id
    users {
        stats {       /// Field-level resolver
            sum       /// Float
        }
    }
}
```

I have difficulties with understanding how to resolve this query conceptually. The `sum` field differs per user per list. So given a `userId` and a `listId`, the `sum` is different. The `userId` I can access from the resolver of the user by using the root of the resolver when resolving the field `stats`, however, I cannot access the `list` node to which the current `user` belongs, so I have no way of getting the `listId`. I have looked at the `info` object that is passed to the resolving function, but it doesn't seem to be including the resolved `list` object.

With such a structure, how do I pass the id of the list to the resolver of stats?

Note that users and lists have a many to many relationship with eachother, so there is no way to determine given only a `userId` which `listId` should be used for the calculation of sum.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60756115/6124657

Comment: That is indeed a similar question, thanks!