# Access args of parent resolver inside field resolver

Tags: javascript, graphql, nestjs

I have this below resolver,

```
  @ResolveField()
  async config(@Parent() pet: Pet, @Context() ctx, @Info() info): Promise<CourseConfig> {
    return await this.petService.getConfig(syllabus, ctx, info);
  }
```

How can I get args  passed to root resolver inside `petServic.getConfig()`?
I know I can use `@Args()` decorator.

But It is only returning `args` passed to the `fieldResolver` i.e. `config(id: "someId")` but not those passed to the root resolver.

Comment: Okay thanks, is there anyway I can get parent args in `fieldResolver` i.e. in `config()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60756115/6124657