# How can I share data between 2 resolver functions in Express GraphQL?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql

I have 2 queries, and corresponding functions, but while writing the resolver, I'm not sure how to store the 1st func data, then reuse it in the second one. Note: I do not want to call the function again as it will be executing again and has an inline API call. I just want to use it like a session on the global state in express js. Here's the code:

```
const resolvers={
    getStudent:async({id})=>{
        const resp=await service(id)
        return resp;
    },
    
    const courseDetails:()=>{
        console.log(resp)// I want to access resp object from above func., But don't want to call getStudent again
    }
}
```

I tried context but didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60756115/6124657 ?

Comment: ... but it's for top-down 'relations', in one 'flow' (single nested query), when data is collected for tree shaped response ... different client, different `id`, different `resp`? use cache?

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/performance/caching/ - different server, different possibilities

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a simple in-memory store.
By storing the `Promise` and returning it you won't need to worry about multiple requests to the same resources.

```
const got = require('got');
const assert = require('assert');

function studentServiceFactory(options = {}) {
    const TTL = options.ttl || 60 * 60 * 5; // default 5 min ttl
    const BASE_API = "https://swapi.dev/api";
    const store = {};

    return {
        get: ({ id }) => {
            if(!store[id] || store[id].timestamp + TTL < Date.now()) {
                // store the promise
                store[id] = {
                    promise: got(`${BASE_API}/people/${id}`),
                    timestamp: Date.now(),
                };
                console.log(`${BASE_API}/people/${id}`);
            }
            return store[id].promise;
        }
    }
}

const studentService = studentServiceFactory({ ttl: 1000});
const resolvers = {
    studentService: studentService,
};


// test program
(async () => {
    const request1 = await resolvers.studentService.get({ id: 1 });
    const request2 = await resolvers.studentService.get({ id: 1 });
    // Both calls will return the same promise.

    assert.equal(request1, request2);

    // wait for resources to get stale 
    setTimeout(async() => {
        const request3 = await resolvers.studentService.get({ id: 1 });
        assert.notEqual(request1, request3);
    }, 3000);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two requests are independent of each other. The only way to share data between two requests is to persist the data somewhere. It can be a file, database, etc. In your case, you can simply call the service function again in the other resolver.

Comment: Yes I thought about that but my objective is to reduce service call. Since it's already fetched above in getStudent, calling it again for courseDetails is what I'm avoiding. How can we persist it on node?

Comment: is there any way we can store response in global state or file? I couldn't find any state management libraries for server side for graph?