# Which executes first? Query or Mutation in graphql?

Tags: node.js, graphql, express-graphql

I'm new to graphql and just wanted to ask which operation executes completely first? Query or Mutation? I went through the docs and it mentions queries are in parallel, and mutations are serial, but if both are present, which one completes first?

I'm trying to convert a GET and POST rest API route to graphql. And the request body of the post request will be the response from GET call. Can anyone tell me how can I implement this logic? I couldn't find any demo/online tutorial for same. Here's one of my previous questions regarding graphql for [code purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69447993/how-can-i-share-data-between-2-resolver-functions-in-express-graphql/69449714#69449714).