# Resolve M:M (many to many) using Federation

Tags: graphql, many-to-many, apollo, federation

**Resolve M:M (many to many) using Federation**

**How to resolve many to many relationships while using GraphQL Federation Micro-Services?**

Lets say Users & Events. They have m:m relationship.
"User_Id" is not stored in "Events" table & "Event_Id" is not stored in "Users" table.

Here i have created 3 micro-services + 1 Api Gateway :

1. Users
2. Events
3. User_Events (bridge table)

"user_events" table have both the ids, user & event entities can be resolved from this bridge table.

Now my concern is:

(A) "user" table does not hold "event_ids", how to write a query to get user details & all the events he/she is attending ?

(B) "events" table does not hold "user_ids", how to write a query to get event details & all the users as its attendees ?

Please help me to resolve this using graphQL Federation Micro-Services.

Comment: So each of the three tables are managed by one micro-service, right?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you :-) [Apollo Server: pass arguments to nested resolvers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60755236/apollo-server-pass-arguments-to-nested-resolvers).

Works the same way with federated services => https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/federation.

Just notice that filtering/sorting/pagination of federated many to many relations is not possible at the moment without breaking separation of concern: https://github.com/apollographql/federation/issues/359

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what framework you use, but it is possible as below in NestJS.

If User_Events (bridge table) is in your Users

You can use like following

In User service

```js
@Resolver(() => User)
export class UserResolver {
  @ResolveField(() => [Events])
  events(@Parent() user: User): Promise< {__typename: string, id: number }[]{
    const userEvents = await userEventsRepo.findByUserId(user.id);
    return userEvents.map((value: UserEvent) => { __typename: 'Event', id: value.eventId });
  }
}
```

In Event Service

```js
@Resolver(() => Event)
export class EventResolver {
  @ResolveReference()
  resolveReference(reference: { __typename: string; id: number }): Promise<Event> {
    return this.eventRepo.findById(reference.id);
  }
}
```

The key is to implement the resolveReference on one service and return __typename on the other service.

If you considering the performance, you can use dataloader in resolveReference