# How can a nested field in graphQL query get its own arguments

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm working on a cursor based pagination that requires the a nested field to access the args. So far, i've been unable to get the args to its desired field.

```
   type Game {
    players(first: Int, after: String, last: Int, before: String): GameToPlayerConnection
  }

  game(id: GameID!): Game
```

I am able to only access the args passed to the `game` and not the args passed to the `players`.

```
 game: async (parent: any, args: { id: string; first: number; last: number; after: 
       string; before: string; }, _ctx: any, info: any) => 
        {
        const { id, first, last, after, before } = args;
        console.log("args", args);
        }



  game(id: 'fortnite', first: 3){
    players(first: 2){
     ....
     }
    }
```

I am trying to access the args passed to the `players`

Comment: Are you using a framework?

Comment: No I'm not. just plain apollo-server-express

Comment: okay ..take a loo at this answer ...seems like a similar problem 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60755236/apollo-server-pass-arguments-to-nested-resolvers

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Every resolver can only access the arguments for its own property. Each object also has its own set of resolvers, so you need one object for Query, and another for Game:

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    game: async (parent, { id }, context, info) {
      return games.load(id);
    },
  },
  Game: {
    players: async ({ id }, { first, last, before, after }, context, info) {
      return playersByGame({
        gameId: id,
        first,
        last,
        before,
        after,
      });
    },
  },
};
```